# Javascript Canvas issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm new here so forgive my ignorance. Hope everyone is having a great friday night. I'm working on a website where there will be a canvas and on that canvas there will be a bar, my goal is to simply get the bar to extend right when I press 'D' and retract left when I press 'A'. I am using the function fillRect and the extending right portion is working great while the retracting portion is not working at all, as I am attempting to use the clearRect function. The clearRect function is clearing the whole original width of my rectangle without and my canvas's light blue color along with it, leaving a stripe of grey bitterness. Here is my code, and if any of you have any idea how I can manage to clear the last 10 pixels of my grey bar while leaving the beautiful blue underlying canvas intact when I press 'A' I will be eternally grateful.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var width=10;
$(document).keydown(function(key){
    if(key.which === 68)    
        adjustWidth(1);
    else if(key.which === 65)
        adjustWidth(2);

});
var canvas=$("#canvas")[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var w = $("#canvas").width();
var h = $("canvas").height();

ctx.fillStyle = "#C1DAD6";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);  
ctx.strokeStyle="black";
ctx.strokeRect(0,0,w,h);

function adjustWidth(iw)
{   ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
if(iw===1){
    ctx.fillRect(0,100,width+10,5)
    width+=10;
    }
 else if(iw===2){
     ctx.clearRect(0,100,width,5)
   width-=10;
 }
}    


});
```

Comment: can you just `fillRect` with blue instead of clearing it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use another approach:

```
var width = 10;

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    ctx.drawRect(0,100,width,5);
}

setInterval(draw, 30);

$(document).keydown(function(key){
    if(key.which === 68)    
        width += 10;
    else if(key.which === 65)
        width -= 10;

});
```

Maybe it looks like heavy but it's not, trust me.

Comment: there is a method `requestAnimationFrame` that is less heavy than `setInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

`clearRect` clears the background too.

Instead save the background first:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var width=10;

    $(document).keydown(function(key){
        if(key.which === 68)    
            adjustWidth(1);
        else if(key.which === 65)
            adjustWidth(2);
    });

    var canvas=$("#canvas")[0];
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var w = $("#canvas").width();
    var h = $("canvas").height();

    ctx.fillStyle = "#C1DAD6";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);  
    ctx.strokeStyle="black";
    ctx.strokeRect(0,0,w,h);
    var saved=ctx.getImageData(0,0,w,h);

    function adjustWidth(iw){
        ctx.putImageData(saved,0,0);
        ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
        if(iw===1){
            width+=10;
        }else if(iw===2){
            width-=10;
        }
        ctx.fillRect(0,100,width,5);
    }
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/bgg96/

Comment: if I may: assuming that the background does indeed need to be saved, maybe a two canvas approach, where the foreground canvas is on top of that with the static background, would be beneficial.

Comment: But here the op draws the background himself instead of having an image.

Comment: I mean you can generate and display the background once on a separate canvas. no need to call `putImageData` every time.

Comment: Thank you so much! The background doesn't need to be saved only redrawn to appear the same so I won't need to do the dual canvases. I really appreciate this!

Answer (score 0):

You must redraw your background with each change in your line (that’s the canvas way)

Don’t worry, **canvas is very fast at redrawing!**

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/WdEWz/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var width=10;

    $(document).keydown(function(key){
        if(key.which === 68)    
            adjustWidth(1);
        else if(key.which === 65)
            adjustWidth(2);
    });

    var canvas=$("#canvas")[0];
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var w = $("#canvas").width();
    var h = $("canvas").height();

    ctx.fillStyle = "#C1DAD6";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);  
    ctx.strokeStyle="black";
    ctx.strokeRect(0,0,w,h);

    function adjustWidth(iw){

        ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#C1DAD6";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);  
        ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
        if(iw===1){
             width+=10;
             ctx.fillRect(0,100,width+10,5)
        }else if(iw===2){
             width-=10;
             if(width>0){
                  ctx.fillRect(0,100,width+10,5)
             }
        }
    } 

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Amazing explanation and very smart approach! I am really thankful for this, and my first time using this website has been very pleasant thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow...Come back soon!